# Entity Framework 6 code first fluent API one to one relation with both ends required

Tags: entity-framework-6, relationship, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

I want to implement One to One relation with both ends required with the fluent API in Entity Framework 6 code first.

I have the principal class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id{ get;  set;} 
    public string Name{ get;  set;}
    public StudentProfile StudentProfile { get; set; } 
}
```

and I have the dependent class:

```
public class StudentProfile
{
    public int Id{ get;  set;} 
    public string Description{ get;  set;}
    public Student Student { get; set; } 
}
```

Additionally, I have the configuration for the relation one to one, in this case both ends ARE REQUIRED:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasRequired(student => student.StudentProfile)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(profile => profile.Student);

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);   
}
```

After executing update-database, the resulting generated tables are:

[image]

The table StudentProfile columns:

[image]

The table Students columns:

[image]

On the Main program, I am able to save a Student with its profile:

```
 UMLModel umlContext = new UMLModel();

 //Studentprofile object
 StudentProfile studentProfile = new StudentProfile();
 studentProfile.Description = "Emily Profile Description";

 //Student object
 Student student = new Student();
 student.Name = "Emily";
 student.StudentProfile = studentProfile;

 //Save Student and StudenProfile Objects
 umlContext.Students.Add(student);
 umlContext.SaveChanges();
```

Once executed the Main program,on the database,the StudentProfiles table is:

[image]

and the Students table is:

[image]

The problem becomes when I try to save one student WITHOUT its profile, the program allows to save it and it is supposed to not allow it:

```
UMLModel umlContext = new UMLModel();

Student student = new Student();
student.Name = "John";

umlContext.Students.Add(student);  
umlContext.SaveChanges();
```

After executing the Main program, on the database, for table StudentProfiles now is:

[image]

and for table Students:

[image]

One way to prevent this is using data annotations, but I don't like this approach due the domain classes needs additional code:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id{ get;  set;} 
    public string Name{ get;  set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual StudentProfile StudentProfile { get; set; } 
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it a bug from the fluent API?
2. Is there any way to solve this problem using the Fluent API without modifying 
   the domain classes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not answering the question, but from a design point of view a one to one relationship with both end required does not make sense. Just create 1  class that contains all the Attributes found in Student and student profile.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at the Stack Overflow answer here, which gives a nice explanation about 1:1 mappings in Entity Framework and some options for how you can map them so both ends are required: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30516623/2128831